# Scrollbar on the whole Layout in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have an issue with the Android layout.

I have some components (here a TableLayout and then a ListView). My scrollbar is associated only with the ListView and not the the TableLayout. As my TableLayout will become longer and in that case, my Listview will be unreadable.

How can I have a scrollbar for the whole page and not only for the ListView ?

My code :

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="77dp" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="@string/client"
            android:width="100px" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/client"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:width="200px" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lstPointsVerification"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</ListView>
```

Here is the code of each line of the ListView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDate" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    style="@style/ListePrincipal"
  />
```

How I correct that behaviour ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one thing that is create a seperate Layout for the `Header` part that is the part above the `ListView` and add it to the `ListView` using `ListView.addHeader(View);`. So, in that case your Layout will scroll with the `ListView`.

Comment: well it's sound that the better solution but ugly. I'll change my code and create a wizard. thank you

Answer (score 1):

> Better put TableLayout inside ScrollView. set height to scrollview.

**You should not put ListView inside ScrollView**

Answer (score 1):

Please see Scroll View in Scroll View is not possible in android, you can implement it but it not work. According to your question, there is only one answer is feasible, we can have two linear layout of fixed height, and then add table layout and listview to these layouts.